# Реально ли создать SurfaceView в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Хочу реализовать `SurfaceView` элементы в `RecyclerView` для создания рисунков при помощи тача. Возможно ли такое? Может кто нибудь знает, как можно реализовать другим образом?

Список который я хочу реализовать будет состоять из `EditText` и картинок между ними. Картинки можно редактировать стилусом. Я с вами согласен что это достаточно нерациональный подход. Но тогда какой элемент вы могли бы предложить взамен `SurfaceView`, пригодный для такой цели? Какой подход для создания элемента был бы наиболее рациональным?

**Обновление**

Вариант с отдельным *Activity* для редактирования картинок отпадает. В таком виде я бы уже давно все реализовал.

Моя цель - это исследование, а не создание идеального приложения. Да и к тому же отрицательный результат - тоже результат. Если вы говорите что это наиболее рациональный подход для моего нерационального приложения, то пусть уж будет так. А возможна ли временная трансформация скажем `ImageView` в `SurfaceView` при двойном нажатии прямо в списке? P.S. Вы спросите, почему я еще не попробовал написать нужный мне элемент. Дело в том что у меня очень мало времени, поэтому путь в никуда, да еще и с откатом назад - мне не нужен.

Comment: А можно по конкретнее, а то непонятно как вы себе это представляете. RecyclerView не для этого предназначен, а делать множество SurfaceView и добавлять их в REcyclerView просто ужас, в особенности для вашей задачи. Вы можете сделать просто свой собственный RecyclerView (1 единственный), в который вы реализуете функционал рисования, для этого не нужно лепить 100 других вьюшек

Comment: На самом деле SurfaceView тут как никто другой лучше подходит, но вопрос в том, что концепция у вас хромате, ибо я ещё не видел таких редакторов, который бы позволял редактировать сразу множество элементов. Даже понятия не имею для чего всё это, но могу сказать одно, пусть вместо SurfaceView будут обычные ImageView, а при нажатии на них или долгом удержании и выборе в контекстном меню вы бы переходили в отдельное Activity, в котором бы уже могли реализовать SurfaceView для редактирования картинки и её последующего сохранения. Вашу изначальную концепцию телефоны не потянут

Comment: А что вы хотите вообще, если там будет редактирование не ресурсоёмкое, то можете попробовать, а так вообще концепция хромает у вас, вы вообще где-нибудь видели подобное? Вы поймите, что если вы собрались реализовывать редактирование а-ля перетащи усы на картинку, то может и не сильно будет нагружать, а если что-то близко похожее хотя бы на paint, то ни один телефон такое не потянет, ибо под каждую картинку свой paint придётся инициализировать

Comment: Да именно так. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

А что вы хотите вообще, если там будет редактирование не ресурсоёмкое, то можете попробовать, а так вообще концепция хромает у вас, вы вообще где-нибудь видели подобное? Вы поймите, что если вы собрались реализовывать редактирование а-ля перетащи усы на картинку, то может и не сильно будет нагружать, а если что-то близко похожее хотя бы на paint, то ни один телефон такое не потянет, ибо под каждую картинку свой paint придётся инициализировать.

Что поповоду перевода ImageView в SurfaceView, тот тут всё очень лёгко, вы можете реализовать этот функционал, вам никто не мешает. Сделай в вашей View отдельный метод для передачи изображения, а далее обрабатывайте его и изменяйте как пожелаете, т.е. из ImageView вы можете получить Bitmap, потом передать его через метод, а в SurfaceView добавляете его в вашу канву, а там редактируете уже, а потом из канвы достаёте новый Bitmap и возвращаете обратно. Надеюсь вы поняли весь смысл, ибо путей реализации бесчисленное множество, я вам скорее предложил правильную концепцию.